# MongoDB-Java performance with rebuilt Sync driver vs Async

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-java, ycsb

I have been testing MongoDB 2.6.7 for the last couple of months using YCSB 0.1.4. I have captured good data comparing SSD to HDD and am producing engineering reports.

After my testing was completed, I wanted to explore the allanbank async driver. When I got it up and running (I am not a developer, so it was a challenge for me), I first wanted to try the rebuilt sync driver. I found performance improvements of 30-100%, depending on the workload, and was very happy with it.

Next, I tried the async driver. I was not able to see much difference between it and my results with the native driver.

The command I'm running is:

```
./bin/ycsb run mongodb -s -P workloads/workloadb -p mongodb.url=mongodb://192.168.0.13:27017/ycsb -p mongodb.writeConcern=strict -threads 96
```

Over the course of my testing (mostly with the native driver), I have experimented with more and less threads than 96; turned on "noatime"; tried both xfs and ext4; disabled hyperthreading; disabled half my 12 cores; put the journal on a different drive; changed sync from 60 seconds to 1 second; and checked the network bandwidth between the client and server to ensure its not oversubscribed (10GbE).

Any feedback or suggestions welcome.

Comment: What issues did you into getting YCSB and the Allanbank driver running.  You can contact me via email if you prefer.  The address is linked off the blog's about page: http://www.allanbank.com/blog/about/.  

I would not expect to see much of a difference between MongoDB Inc.'s async driver and their native driver. First, YCSB is inherently synchronous and the core of the MongoDB Inc drivers works in the same way so they do not benefit from the asynchronous advantages - with YCSB. Second don't think they have spent that much time performance tuning yet.

Comment: Which fork of YCSB are you using?  The original YCSB hasn't been updated much - I would recommend testing against 3.0.1 MongoDB in particular with new storage engine.  If you are limited by the client then you will know, otherwise expect 3 to 7x improvement (depending on the workload).

Answer (score 0):

The Async move exceeded my expectations. My experience is with the Python Sync (pymongo) and Async driver (motor) and the Async driver achieved greater than 10x the throughput. further, motor is still using pymongo under the hoods but adds the async ability. that could easily be the case with your allanbank driver.

Often the dramatic changes come from threading policies and OS configurations.

Async needn't and shouldn't use any more threads than cores on the VM or machine. For example, if you're server code is spawning a new thread per incoming conn -- then all bets are off. start by looking at the way the driver is being utilized. A 4 core machine uses <= 4 incoming threads.

On the OS level, you  may have to fine-tune parameters like net.core.somaxconn, net.core.netdev_max_backlog, sys.fs.file_max, /etc/security/limits.conf nofile and the best place to start is looking at nginx related performance guides [including this one](http://nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/). nginx is the server that spearheaded or at least caught the attention of many linux sysadmin enthusiasts. Contrary to popular lore one should reduce your keepalive timeout opposed to lengthen it. The default keep-alive timeout is some absurd (4 hours) number of seconds. you might want to cut the cord in 1 minute. basically, think a short sweet relationship with your clients connections.

Bear in mind that Mongo is not Async so you can use a Mongo driver pool. nevertheless, don't let the driver get stalled on slow queries. cut it off in 5 to 10 seconds using the following equivalents in Java. I'm just cutting and pasting here with no recommendations.

```
# Specifies a time limit for a query operation. If the specified time is exceeded, the operation will be aborted and ExecutionTimeout is raised. If max_time_ms is None no limit is applied.
# Raises TypeError if max_time_ms is not an integer or None. Raises InvalidOperation if this Cursor has already been used.
CONN_MAX_TIME_MS = None

# socketTimeoutMS: (integer) How long (in milliseconds) a send or receive on a socket can take before timing out. Defaults to None (no timeout).
CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS=None

# connectTimeoutMS: (integer) How long (in milliseconds) a connection can take to be opened before timing out. Defaults to 20000.
CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS=20000

# waitQueueTimeoutMS: (integer) How long (in milliseconds) a thread will wait for a socket from the pool if the pool has no free sockets. Defaults to None (no timeout).
CLIENT_WAIT_QUEUE_TIMEOUT_MS=None

# waitQueueMultiple: (integer) Multiplied by max_pool_size to give the number of threads allowed to wait for a socket at one time. Defaults to None (no waiters).
CLIENT_WAIT_QUEUE_MULTIPLY=None
```

Hopefully you will have the same success. I was ready to bail on Python prior to async